# Shuffling a string in Swift - swapping a location not supported

Tags: string, swift, shuffle

I have this code to shuffle a string in swift. For some reason it is giving an error in Xcode 7.1 "swapping a location with itself is not supported. I thought it was working ok. Any ideas where I have gone wrong much appreciated!

```
let selectedWord = word1 // word1 is a string
var chars = Array(selectedWord.characters)
chars.shuffleString()
let shuffledWord = String(chars)
word1 = shuffledWord

extension Array {
mutating func shuffleString() {
    for index in 0..<(count - 1) {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - index))) + index
        swap(&self[index], &self[j]) // error on this line saying 'swapping a location with itself is not supported'
```

Comment: Just an added note — that code will crash if you try it with an empty string, since 0 ..< -1 isn't allowed.

Comment: thanks Nate. I just saw that excellent long answer from you and others to this question. Sorry for the duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

The `swap` function changed in a recent version of Xcode to prevent swapping a variable with itself. You can add a `guard` statement just before your swap to make sure `index` and `j` aren't the same:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffleString() {
        for index in 0..<(count - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - index))) + index
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap(&self[index], &self[j])
        }
    }
}
```